# continue behavior in camel route execution

Tags: java, apache-camel

I want to put continue behaviour in route, my route is like following

```
from("file:D:\\?fileName=abc.csv&noop=true").split().unmarshal().csv() 
.to("direct:insertToDb").end();

from("direct:insertToDb")
.to("direct:getDataId")
.to("direct:getDataParameters")
.to("direct:insertDataInDb");

from("direct:getDataId")
.to("sql:SELECT id FROM data WHERE name = :#name)
.choice()
.when(header("id").isGreaterThan(0) )
.setProperty("id", header("id"))
.otherwise()
.log("Error for")
.endChoice().end();
```

I want that if direct:getDataId dont find any record , my execution of route for current record from CSV get skip and program process next request. it would be equal to continue keyword.

How i can achieve this in Apache Camel route?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your routes like this:

```
from("file:D:\\?fileName=abc.csv&noop=true").split().unmarshal().csv() 
.to("sql:SELECT id FROM data WHERE name = :#name?outputHeader=id&outputType=SelectOne)
.choice().when(header("id").isGreaterThan(0))
    .to("direct:getDataParameters")
    .to("direct:insertDataInDb")
.end();
```

Comment: if suppose direct:getDataParameters didnt get data then i have to put one more condition.

Comment: You just skip two other routes by condition which depends on SQL query results. And you have to modify you "direct:getDataId" route, to put query result into header. You can use "outputHeader" option (camel.apache.org/sql-component.html). This allows to preserve the existing message body (from csv) as-is. I edited my example, look at it again, please.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got a test for this? I suggest you try using CamelTestSupport because what you want is how camel will execute by default.

From [Camel Split Docs](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html):

- stopOnException
- default:false
- description: Whether or not to stop continue processing immediately when an exception occurred. If disable, then Camel continue splitting and process the sub-messages regardless if one of them failed. You can deal with exceptions in the AggregationStrategy class where you have full control how to handle that.